# How to find the sum of the numbers that are between the two given integers in Java

Tags: java, numbers

I need to write a method of the sum of the numbers that are between the two given integers.

For example, the call sumNums(1,3) should return 6 because 1+2+3 = 6.

The call sumNums(3,1) should also return 6.

So far I have

```
public static int sumNum(int num1, int num2)
{
   int min = Math.min(num1, num2);
   int max = Math.max(num1, num2);
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = min; i < max; i++)
   {
       sum += i;
   }
        sum =+ max;
   return sum;
}
```

any other methods would help, but if there's a way initialize the sum and return it it would help.

Comment: `int sum = 0;` ?

Comment: @Fredk yea I forgot to put that in. It's in.

Comment: @rgettman yes, I put it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int sumNum(int num1, int num2) {
        int min = Math.min(num1, num2);
        int max = Math.max(num1, num2);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: I will try this out.

Comment: Yeah, but it will fail when you call with 3, 1 because i didn't see your edit

Comment: You can try it now

Comment: This approach is hugely inefficient - you can calculate the result without having to iterate through the set of values (which takes longer the larger the range is).

Comment: @Jason you should add your answer to improve the existing answers and show the efficient way

Answer (score 2):

Honestly using java-8 `IntStream`

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).sum();    //6
```

using java-7 and below

```
public static int sumNum(int num1, int num2)
 {
    int min = Math.min(num1, num2);
    int max = Math.max(num1, num2);
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
     {
        sum += i;
      }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I don't have java-8

Answer (score 1):

It's (simple) math:

```
public static int sumNum(int num1, int num2) {
   int min = Math.min(num1, num2);
   int max = Math.max(num1, num2);
   return max * (max + 1) / 2 - min * (min - 1) / 2
}
```

Comment: Or `((max+min) * (max+1-min))/2`

Comment: (Simple) math to the rescue once again!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something likes this:

```
return (num1 + num2) / 2.0 * (Math.abs(num1 - num2) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach will encounter performance problems the larger the gap between the two integers. There are optimisations you can make.

For example, if you have an odd number of integers:

```
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4

1 + 2 + 3 = 2 + 2 + 2

5 + 6 + 7 = 6 + 6 + 6
```

See the pattern?

```
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4
                  = 5 * 4
                  = (max - min + 1) * ((max + min) / 2)
```

For an even number of integers:

```
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 3.5 + 3.5 + 3.5 + 3.5
              = 4 * 3.5

5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 7.5 + 7.5 + 7.5 + 7.5 + 7.5 + 7.5
                       = 6 * 7.5
```

Looking familiar! Let's see if our previous formula works:

```
2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = (max - min + 1) * ((max + min) / 2)
              = (5 - 2 + 1) * ((5 + 2) / 2)
              = 4 * 3.5
```

The formula can be simplified:

```
(max - min + 1) * ((max + min) / 2)  =  (max - min + 1) * (max + min) / 2
```

Therefore:

```
public static int sumNum(int num1, int num2) {
    int min = Math.min(num1, num2);
    int max = Math.max(num1, num2);
    return (max - min + 1) * (max + min) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using math to get it in constant time:

```
sum = max * (max + 1) / 2 - (min * (min - 1)) /2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to learn Java (iterations and streams) or if you are looking for a good solution to a real problem. In the latter case, your problem is a sum of terms of an Arithmetic progression [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).
The sum of its terms starting at from `m` to `n` is given by the `product` of the number of terms (i.e: `m - n +1`) and the sum of first and last terms the all divided by 2:

```
(max - min + 1)*(min + max)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much different from the others but this would be my sollution

```
public static int sumNum(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 > num2) {
        int temp = num2;
        num2 = num1;
        num1 = temp;
    }
    return (num1 + num2) * (num2 + 1 - num1) / 2;
}
```